# Why is read loop skipping lines?

Tags: python

I can't tell why my read file loop is skipping lines.

I'm trying to write a simple program in python to parse a txt document before running it in another.  What I essentially have is a text file that looks like a triangle that I'm trying to parse into a list in a list i.e.

```
1

2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9 10
```

into

```
[[1],[2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]]
```

However, in my code below, my while loop seems like it's "skipping" every other line so instead of getting the above list, I get something like `[[2,3],[7,8,9,10]]`.  What's even more baffling is that if i comment out the last line, the while loop will print '1' exactly the correct number of times

```
f = open('test.txt')
triangle = []

while f.readline() != '':
    print 1
    triangle.append(map(int,f.readline().strip().split()))
```

Comment: There is no need to do both `.strip()` and `.split()` operations. `map(int, f.readline().split())` will work just fine.

Answer (score 11):

Every time you call `f.readline()`, you read a line.  Since you call `f.readline()` inside the loop, you are reading an extra line inside the loop.  A simpler way to do what you want is to iterate directly over the file:

```
for line in f:
    # do whatever you want with the line.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example genereates `[[], [], [], []]`  if you simply add a empty line at the top of the file you get this `[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]`

could also try this:

```
triangle = [ [int(value) for value in line.split(' ') if value.strip()] 
                 for line in open('test.txt') if line.strip()]
```

list comprehenssions *can be* faster then standard loops. tested it, it works, this code can also work regardless of empty lines, its safer, assuming all your entries are integers.

Apparently not everyone likes LC so:

```
triangle = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        if line.strip():
            value = []
            for number in line.split(' '):
                if number.strip():
                    try:
                        value.append(int(number))
                    except Exception as ex:
                        print 'Failed to convert %s at line %i' % (number, index)
                        print 'Exception %s' % str(ex)                        
                        raise ex
            triangle.append(value)
print triangle
```

produces `[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]`

Now some may like LC some may like the standard for loop, its all a matter of opinion/taste, though yes, the for loop those have `try ... except ...` which is a bit nicer since it can tell you at which line failed, though again I did mention that the LC would be ok as long as all the values are integers.

```
$ python -m timeit 'execfile("test.py")'
10000 loops, best of 3: 198 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'execfile("test1.py")'
10000 loops, best of 3: 130 usec per loop
```

so basically a `35%` improvement vs standard for, again its really up to the individual. I personally work with very large datasets and so I try to optimize it as much as possible.

Comment: List comprehensions are 3-4 times faster than what? Unless you'll be reading several million-line pyramids a minute, a readable loop is orders of magnitude faster than the time you'll spend debugging a "clever" one. Stick with `for line in f:`, as in the top-voted answer.

Comment: @alexis in general LC are faster though `3-4` is the best case scenario, this is what my benchmarks tell me, sometimes it may be just a 20% bump, but I'll take anything `python` is actually very slow compared to other languages, then again its also faster then some :)

Comment: I'll be more blunt than alexis, that's one of the worst samples of Python I've ever read. Also, you have a defect in line 1.

Comment: @msw oh Im sorry to hear that, I've removed it.

Comment: @samy you miss the point: Python programs my not run as fast as C programs, but they are *a lot* faster to write and debug.

Comment: As for list comprehensions: they are great, we all like them, but it is not helpful to throw them at someone who is trying to learn their way around file input. (Besides I must agree with @msw, that's pretty ugly code :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('data1.txt') as f:
        lis=[map(int,x.split()) for x in f if x.strip()]
print(lis)

[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

**explanation:**

read the file line by line using `for x in f` and skip those lines whose value after applying `strip()` becomes equal to `False` or `''`.

Then use `map()` and `split()` to create list of `int`.

Comment: Posting code without any explanation does not help understanding.